# No networking possible after AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, afnetworking-2

In my iOS app, I have a dedicated setup screen. The user sees a spinner, while in the background some data is pulled from the Feedly API. It looks like this:

**SetupViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SetupViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**SetupViewController.m**

```
@interface SetupViewController ()

//some other variables

@property (nonatomic) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;

@end

@implementation SetupViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *accessToken = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"AccessToken"];

    _manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    _manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [_manager GET:@"https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/categories"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Do something with responseObject
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             //Do something with the error
         }];

    [_manager GET:@"https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/profile"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Do something with responseObject
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             //Do something with the error
         }];

    [_manager GET:@"https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/subscriptions"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             //Do something with responseObject
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             //Do something with the error
         }];
}

- (void)endIt {
    [_manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"SignedIn"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"finishedSetup" sender:self];
}

@end
```

All this is working great. However, after [self endIt]; is called there is no networking possible in the app. The app doesn't load any UIWebViews or other AFNetworking requests. I have to close it and then reopen it for it to work again.

My idea was that there are too many AFNetworking requests and this creates some kind of bottle neck, but that wouldn't explain why UIWebViews don't even load. What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

Below you can see one of the `UIWebView`s that's not loading - It only logs that the link is loading.

```
#import "TestbackViewController.h"

@interface TestbackViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestbackViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-64)];
    webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/test";
    NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [webview setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    self.title = @"Test";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Loading URL :%@",request.URL.absoluteString);

    //return FALSE; //to stop loading
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Webview started loading.");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Webview finished loading.");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load with error :%@",[error debugDescription]);

}

@end
```

Comment: Try to implement UIWebViewDelegate protocol method, such as start load, finish load.

Comment: @gabbler If I do that, the WebView starts loading, but never finishes.

Comment: So it maybe failed to load, try to implement did fail protocol function and log error message.

Comment: @gabbler I actually did after your previous comment. So even with that function implemented it only logs the loading part...

Comment: Switch to another url and see if the problem still there.

Comment: How did you load the webviews, can you show the code?

Comment: @gabbler I added it to the question and I have indeed tried it out with several urls.

Comment: If you try to load the webview when you launch the app, will it load? I see that after `[self endIt]`, you are going to another page with webview?

Comment: @gabbler Yes, if I open the view without the setup view first, it loads just fine. When the setup view opens this testview through the `segue` in `[self endIt]` it doesn't load.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, the same code worked for me. I loaded two get requests and then immediately went to the webview, which loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I wasn't returning a BOOL for `shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:`. This solved it:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}
```